# How can I make my Graphviz graphs have large text?

Tags: graphviz

I generate graphs based on some static code analysis I perform on old VB6 code.

Problem is the fonts are too small for printing, even on our A3 printer.

I've set the font size large but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Here's the original DOT:

http://pastebin.com/hVD8xKDZ

Here's DOT run through unflatten -l 20:

http://pastebin.com/gchwENKE

The command to generate is just:

dot -Tpng -o"output" -Kdot"input"

But the font is always too small to read printed on A3.

Here's the graph settings:

```
This makes the arrows merge
concentrate=true,

Laser printer resolution
dpi=600,

It's the dot language
layout=dot,

Doesn't seem to do much
overlap=true,

The ratio of A3 paper
ratio=1.4142,

The size of A3 paper in inches
size="11.69,16.53"
```

If I get rid of ratio, the lines are shorter, the text appears to be larger but the diagram is not A3 shaped.

Without the DPI or size, dot.exe just crashes.

Why doesn't it make the fonts larger?

Why doesn't unflatten stagger the nodes as it should?

Why does it create a daft ratio without ratio even though I've stated the dpi and size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot open the link of your dot file.

However, it is easy to adjust font size in dot language

```
digraph foo {
        fontsize = 10
        ...
}
```

Comment: Really? They work for me and I've got them set to public. I've got `node [fontsize=48];` in the dot though. But it's a really wide graph and I can't get it to square it and enlarge the nodes.

Comment: Sounds like you need to change the layout algorithm?

Comment: Layout is dot. What else is there? The documentation doesn't seem to list them at all: http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dlayout

Comment: dot has several layout algorithm: dot,neato,twopi,circo,fdp... just try circo and neato.

Comment: So far fdp  has produced something usable.

Comment: If you are trying to view a really large graph, you may want to try Gephi.

Comment: OK, now I've tried neato and it pretty much nails it. Thanks for that. They're never going to be really large and they're only ever going to get smaller (as there's less and less VB6) so I think we're good. If you put some of the conclusions in your answer I'll tick it.